# Cancel match chess online

Tags: rules

If I played chess online, there is an option to cancel the match. Does official chess game allow it or what rules define it?

Comment: I don't think the official match is allowed to cancel. We are forced to finish the match.We have an option of resigning the game for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't cancel the match once it is started. Your only option is to resign in such case.

You're referencing something called "abort" where the match is ended with no result for either side. There is no option to "abort" in modern competitive chess, but it is worth mentioning that a few decades ago it was the norm to [adjourn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjournment_%28games%29) games that took an unreasonably long amount of time (i.e. played long into the night). It would be resumed at a later time convenient to both players.

Comment: are there some rules or something which defined it??

Comment: or I just can not do that in official match.. ^^.. 


I'll accepted this now with `Exception`..

Comment: thanks for the history.. I accepted this now without `Exception`. ^^